# How to process incoming calls asynchronously to WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service that is being called from a web application (Web App) that is used by multiple users.

It takes some time for the WCF service to process a single request (e.g. 30 seconds).

I have noticed that if I open the Web App in two tabs or in two browser windows and make the Web App send two requests to the WCF service, they are processed subsequently. That is WCF will start processing the second request only after the first request will be processed to the end.

Is there a way to make the WCF service process incoming requests in parallel?

Comment: I can assume that all request came from WebApp server, so there is only one instance of your service. You should modify you WCF logic and implement some `background workers/ async await` model. Or change comunication scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Just because technology allows you to do something doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Here are the instructions for the dangerous tool you're asking for help developing. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-implement-an-asynchronous-service-operation

Every programmer should understand the complexity an accessible, distributed process makes possible. In short, they centralize user requirements. Harvard Business Review proves DRY is a bad practice.
http://www.powersemantics.com/p.html

Proceed at your own discretion. I've given you an alternative.